# How to read .xlsb file in Talend?

Tags: talend

Does anyone know how to read an .xlsb file in Talend?

Using classic `tFileInputExcel` component does not work since it does not support the binary files.

Could you please advise on the available options?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not possible with standard tFileExcel* components in Talend.

There exist some custom components on Talend exchange portal. Such as, tFileExcelWorkbookOpen and tFileExcelWorkbookSave.

https://exchange.talend.com/?&_ga=2.189591531.1788996607.1569762681-1451225792.1569762681#marketplaceproductoverview:marketplace=marketplace%252F1&p=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F542&pi=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F542%252Fitems%252F2807